# Table of contents google doc

Tags: google-apps-script

i'm using a google docs as a template that already contains a table of content created manually. ([issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2502) ) In the code below i insert a heading. My question is:

Why the table of content doesn't refresh automatically???
I don't want to enter in the document and refresh the toc manually for each document...

Ho i can solve this problem??
Thank you in advance

```
var doc=DocumentApp.openById("1gzPXkIbykQlfpIvIth27IqWaukXX00Q29KVCwiSndV8");
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var rowsData = [['Plants', 'Animals'], ['Ficus', 'Goat'], ['Basil', 'Cat'], ['Moss', 'Frog']];
  Logger.log(body.appendParagraph("prova")
      .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).getLinkUrl());
```

Comment: You've pointed to the issue in the issue-tracker, so you already know that programmatic generation or refresh of the table of contents isn't supported. What is your question?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't saw the last comment in issue tracker. I supposed the issue was regarding only "Create Table Of Contents through DocumentApp", but in the last one comment is reported also the refresh problem.